# How to add extra data to a member in MDS?

Tags: sql, wcf, master-data-services

I'm running MDS on a virtual machine and trying to access the service from my host OS.
I've been able to add something to the database but my data is all over the place and in the Master Data Manager (website) I don't see the new member.
I suppose I shouldn't be using Attributes but something else but what and how? Are there tutorials because I can't find any ...?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
International international = new International();

EntityMembers entityMembers = new EntityMembers();

// Set the modelId, versionId, and entityId.
entityMembers.ModelId = new Identifier { Name = modelName };
entityMembers.VersionId = new Identifier { Name = versionName };
entityMembers.EntityId = new Identifier { Name = entityName };
entityMembers.MemberType = memberType;

Collection<Member> members = new Collection<Member>();
Member aNewMember = new Member();
aNewMember.MemberId = new MemberIdentifier() { Name = employee.FullName, Code = aNewCode, MemberType = memberType };

Collection<MDS.Attribute> attributes = new Collection<MDS.Attribute>();

MDS.Attribute attrOrgUnit = new MDS.Attribute();
attrOrgUnit.Identifier = new Identifier() { Name = "OrganizationalUnit" };
attrOrgUnit.Value = employee.OrganizationalUnit;
attrOrgUnit.Type = AttributeValueType.String;
attributes.Add(attrOrgUnit);

aNewMember.Attributes = attributes.ToArray();
members.Add(aNewMember);
entityMembers.Members = members.ToArray();

// Create a new entity member
OperationResult operationResult = new OperationResult();
clientProxy.EntityMembersCreate(international, entityMembers, false, out operationResult);
HandleOperationErrors(operationResult);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to fix my own problem.

First of all: creating separate variables with collections and converting them to arrays afterwards is not necessary. The code from the tutorials works but fails to mention that, when adding the service reference, you have to configure it (right-click on the service reference -> configure) to use Collections as "Collection type" instead of arrays and to generate message contracts.

Second, the code above with the attributes is correct and works perfectly. The problem I had which failed to add messages with attributes was unrelated. It was a connection/authentication problem between my Host OS and Guest OS.

Hope this helps someone.